# Can't store user input from <from> in the react state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a  in reactjs. I am trying to store the user input in the react state object. My code is based on the example given on reactjs.com. But it seems like my input does not get stored at all in the state object.

```
class CreateMovieForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {title: '', grade: '1'};

    this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleGradeChange = this.handleGradeChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
  }
  handleTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({title: event.target.title});
  }

  handleGradeChange(event){
    this.setState({grade: event.target.grade});
  }

  handleSave(event){
    console.log('Titel: ' + this.state.title, 'Betyg: ' + this.state.grade);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSave}>
        <div className={this.props.attr}>
          <label htmlFor='movieTitle'>Titel:</label>
          <input type='text' className={this.props.from} placeholder='Titel här...' title={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleChange}/>
        </div>
        <div className={this.props.attr}>
          <label htmlFor='grade'>Betyg:</label>
          <select id='grade' className={this.props.from} grade={this.state.grade} onChange={this.handleGradeChange}>
              <option>Välj betyg här...</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button className='btn btn-info'>{this.props.btn} </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
  
}
```

Comment: try change `event.target.title` to `event.target.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event target does not have properties called `title` or `grade`, those are your custom terms.  The property you're looking for is `value`:

```
handleTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({title: event.target.value});
}

handleGradeChange(event){
    this.setState({grade: event.target.value});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Dawid already answered the main bit, but I think following refactor might be useful.

```js
 constructor(props){

    ...
    this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

handleChange({name, target: {value}}) {
    this.setState(data => ({
      ...data,
      [name]: value
    }));
}
```

```
<input type='text' name="title" className={this.props.from} placeholder='Titel här...' value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
<select id='grade' name="grade" className={this.props.from} value={this.state.grade} onChange={this.handleChange}>
```

Comment: Updated answer. You have to also change `grade={this.state.grade}` `title={this.state.title}`  to `value=<this.state.<prop>>`